# Specifying LoggingSystem property in Spring Boot doesn't override logback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, logging

Referencing, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.9/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration

It mentions to add the following system variable with the fully qualified path to the LoggingSystem you want to use, so I added the following to my `application.properties` file:

```
org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem
```

After which I ran `mvn clean install` and ran my project using:

```
mvn -X spring-boot:run <set env vars> -f "$(pwd)"/ai-app/pom.xml
```

My pom has the following config:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I even tried setting the value to `none` in the properties but to no avail. It was still using logback.

In the code I access the logger as follows:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
...
...
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(<class_name>.class);
```

Where below is a sample of the log output by the custom `LOGGER`

```
2022-04-04 18:02:04.639  INFO 58294 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] c.v.v.a.s.d.service.SomeServiceImpl  : Files saved to successfully
```

I also tried passing in the variable via command in the two following ways:

1: `-Dorg.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem`

2: `spring-boot:run "-Dorg.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem"`

both of which would be included as part of the command above to run the app.

If anyone has an idea what I have to do here it would be appreciated. From the docs is says that I should be able to override the default without having to *exclude* the logging starter and explicitly *including* the log4j starter.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**:

after a discussion in the comments, I followed: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.system-properties (both adding jvmRunArgs + systemProperties in the pom as a var to the maven plugin)  and got the following error when running `mvn spring-boot:run`:

```
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
[DEBUG] JVM argument(s): -Xverify:none -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dorg.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=Log4J2LoggingSystem
[DEBUG] Classpath for forked process: /Us...
...
...
[DEBUG] Application argument(s): --safetyai.entities.libpostal.datadir=/Users/farazoman/Documents/workspace/extra/datadir/libpostal --spring.profiles.active=local
[DEBUG] Environment variable(s):
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/AbstractFilter
...
...
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.9:run (default-cli) on project ai-app: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.9:run (default-cli) on project ai-app: Application finished with exit code: 1
```

looks like the error is with, I may have to import log4j Core, although that doesn't look clear from the original doc :/

```
[DEBUG] Environment variable(s):
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/AbstractFilter
```

Comment: The doc says to add it as system property, not in application.properties (i.e. you have to provide the LoggingSystem configuration as -D parameter when launching the application).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between the two, I wasn't able to tell the diff, @dunni So I tried that and it didn't change that logback was still being used.

Comment: Can you show the exact command that you used? Just specifying system properties with the Maven command will not provide them to the application process as well, you have to use a specific parameter for that (check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.system-properties)

Comment: @dunni I tried it with the document you referenced, both via mvn cmd line args, and setting the value in the pom. I ended up getting an error on Environment Variables saying no class found for a Core library. I'll look more into it and see what happens. Thanks for the help!